I cant see my logs in my kotlin multiplatform project
I am developing kotlin multiplatform project when I run project I want to see my ktor response in my log
below my CurrencyApiServiceImpl.kt
package data.remote.api
import domain.CurrencyApiService
import domain.model.ApiResponse
import domain.model.Currency
import domain.model.RequestState
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.call.body
import io.ktor.client.plugins.DefaultRequest
import io.ktor.client.plugins.HttpTimeout
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.ContentNegotiation
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.client.request.headers
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.Logging
import io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.LogLevel
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.json
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

class CurrencyApiServiceImpl : CurrencyApiService {
    companion object {
        const val ENDPOINT = "https://api.currencyapi.com/v3/latest"
        const val API_KEY = "cur_live_7fIujvQxlDmWLEjp5mo4VrZDvHZ1dMCqm5kkdhPv"
    }

    private val httpClient = HttpClient {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                prettyPrint = true
                isLenient = true
                ignoreUnknownKeys = true
            })
        }
        install(HttpTimeout) {
            requestTimeoutMillis = 15000
        }
        install(DefaultRequest) {
            headers {
                append("apikey", API_KEY)
            }
        }
        install(Logging) {
            logger = object : io.ktor.client.plugins.logging.Logger {
                override fun log(message: String) {
                    println("HTTP Client Log: $message")
                }
            }
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
    }

    override suspend fun getLatestExchangeRate(): RequestState<List<Currency>> {
        println("Starting request to $ENDPOINT")
        return try {
            val response = httpClient.get(ENDPOINT)
            println("Received response with status: ${response.status}")
            if (response.status.value == 200) {
                val responseBody = response.body<String>()
                println("Response Body: $responseBody")
                val apiResponse = Json.decodeFromString<ApiResponse>(responseBody)
                println("Successfully parsed API response")
                RequestState.Success(data = apiResponse.data.values.toList())
            } else {
                println("Received HTTP error: ${response.status}")
                RequestState.Error(message = "HTTP Error code ${response.status}")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Exception occurred during HTTP request: ${e.message}")
            RequestState.Error(message = e.message ?: "Unknown error")
        }
    }
}

my Model response class
import kotlinx.serialization.SerialName
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable


@Serializable
data class ApiResponse(
    val metadata:MetaData,
    val data: Map<String, Currency>
)
@Serializable
data class MetaData(
    @SerialName("last_updated_at")
    val lastUpdatedAt: String
)
@Serializable
data class Currency(

    var code: String,
    var value: Double
)

I cant see the result in the log I have followed StackOverflow answers and tutorials did not help any help appreciated highly

What platform are you not seeing logs on? The Logging plugin uses STDOUT, so my first thought is that you might need to specify a different destination. Napier itself is a multiplatform logger, but their readme is also a good list of the various platform log destinations - https://github.com/AAkira/Napier
